# Why does my layout view animate its size before its sibling has changed its size?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-animation

I have a simple layout with 4 LinearLayout groups each holding a different type of view. What I am trying to do is start off the screen by have the LinearLayouts "collapsed" by turning their child's visibility to View.GONE. On each layout, as well as the layout's parent, I have android:animateLayoutChanges="true" so that when I click on the Layout (which is set to clickable), its child will have its visibility set to View.VISIBLE, thus expanding its parent LinearLayout nicely.

All this works fine when I set its visibility to View.VISIBLE, but when I click it again, I set it back to View.GONE so that the LinearLayout will shrink.

The problem I am facing is that when it shrinks, it seems like the LinearLayout's height gets updated immediately before it has time to start animating, so its siblings below it animate upwards immediately, looking quick bad.

Here is a small animation of what's going on:

[image]

I can tell that the child (the DatePicker) starts to fade out when I set the visibility to View.GONE.

Here is some code to show how I am approaching this (irrelevant items were left out):

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/layoutMain"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:clipChildren="false"
    tools:context=".QuickAddMain">

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:clipChildren="false">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
            android:clipChildren="false"
            android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/testGroup03"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
                android:background="@drawable/section_background"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/testTitle03Clickable"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="?android:selectableItemBackground"
                    android:clickable="true">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/testTitle03"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                        android:text="Test Title 03"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />

                </LinearLayout>

                <DatePicker
                    android:id="@+id/datePicker"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:calendarViewShown="false"
                    android:datePickerMode="spinner"
                    android:visibility="gone" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/testGroup04"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="70dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
                android:background="@drawable/section_background"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_below="@+id/dateGroup">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/testTitle04Clickable"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="?android:selectableItemBackground"
                    android:clickable="true">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/testTitle04"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                        android:text="Test Title 04"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />

                </LinearLayout>

                <TimePicker
                    android:id="@+id/timePicker"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:timePickerMode="spinner"
                    android:visibility="gone" />
            </LinearLayout>

        </RelativeLayout>
    </ScrollView>
```

Java:

```
LayoutTransition layoutTransition;

layoutTransition = dateGroup.getLayoutTransition();
layoutTransition.enableTransitionType(LayoutTransition.CHANGING);

layoutTransition = timeGroup.getLayoutTransition();
layoutTransition.enableTransitionType(LayoutTransition.CHANGING);
```

---

```
    dateActivation = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.dateActivation);
    dateActivation.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (datePicker.getVisibility() == View.GONE) {
                datePicker.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            } else {
                datePicker.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        }
    });

    timeActivation = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.timeActivation);
    timeActivation.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (timePicker.getVisibility() == View.GONE) {
                timePicker.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            } else {
                timePicker.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        }
    });
```

Please let me know if I'm missing anything or if anything needs to be clarified. Thanks.

Comment: Did you manage to solve this?

Comment: No solution found yet..

Comment: @hellaandrew I am facing same problem... is it solved?

Comment: @hellaandrew  is it solved?